# How to get rid of this little bar of link under a link image?

Tags: html, css, hyperlink

[image: There is a little invisible bar of link under my image, which IS a link.]

There is a little invisible bar of link under my image, which IS a link.
Is there any way to make this bar go away or be un-selectable/un-clickable?

Thanks!

Comment: Questions seeking code help must include the shortest code necessary to reproduce it **in the question itself** preferably in a [**Stack Snippet**](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2014/09/introducing-runnable-javascript-css-and-html-code-snippets/).  See [**How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/reprex)

Comment: I think that's the container for the image, try making the anchor tag display: block so chrome highlights the element correctly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can you please check the below code? Hope it will work for you. This issue arrived because `<a>` tag is an inline element. You need no add style for `<a>` tag.

You can compare the following example (with and without `display` property).

```css
.link-block {
  display: inline-flex;
}
```

```html
<a href="#" class="link-block">
  <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/240x200" alt="placeholder">
</a>
<hr />
<a href="#" class="">
  <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/240x200" alt="placeholder">
</a>
```

Note: You can use inline-block, block, inline-flex, or flex as per your requirements in `.link-block` class.

Answer (score -1):

You can add a css property to the  tag like so:

```
<a href="" style="display: none;"></a>
```

This will prevent the link from being displayed or clicked.
If you prefer to separate out your css and html you can do the following:

```
<style>
    .noDisplay {
        display: none;
    }
</style>
<a href="" class="noDisplay"></a>
```

To learn more about html and css you could checkout out [freecodecamp.org](https://www.freecodecamp.org/).